# I can't find my MinGW shell after installing with GUI installer

Tags: shell, mingw

I used Mingw_get_inst and installed the MinGW compiler suite following the instructions on the howto page. I used the GUI installer. I then changed the path to include C:\MingW; . When I go to Start menu -> all programs -> MingW the only file that exists inside of there is a uninstaller. The howto page says a shell should be there... can someone help me get this working?

Howto page on Mingw.org: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started

Comment: Could you post the link of the question you posted on minw mailing group? Also did the answer solve your problem (seeing you didn't upvote it)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at the install logs for your Mingw.

I have 2 bin dirs in my (single) installation of Mingw

```
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin
```

and

```
C:\MinGW\bin
```

A lot has changed about Mingw in the last 2-3 years and I think some documentation you might find easily via google is out-of-date.

Try asking for help at [mingw mail groups via Nabble (very easy to use)](http://mingw.5.n7.nabble.com/)

IHTH

Comment: I did try that, but so far no one has replied. Perhaps they will in the future. But I am very anxious to get started maybe you could help me? I'm not sure where to locate my install log, I've searched as well. I've also taken a direct look at the directory and there is no "msys" folder there. Am I missing something?

Comment: per the instruction page you mention above, downloading installers from https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Installer/mingw-get-inst/ OR http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Automated%20MinGW%20Installer/mingw-get/ are just installers, you need to run those to setup mingw. Did you do that. If you don't have msys, I don't think you have a complete install. You may have to wait a few days for a response on your problem. Good luck.

Comment: Re-reading your message, I see you ran the Gui Installer. (I saw that you don't have the msys dir, but do you have a c:\mingw\bin dir?) I would recommend running the uninstaller, and then re-installing, this time taking care to make notes of all inputs that you gave to the installer and possibly do a screen capture of your windows file browser centered at c:\mingw. Post them as part of your question and I'll take a look at it when I can(probably not for 24 hrs). Good luck.

Comment: I reinstalled and installed what I did at first try, the C and C++ compilers. I did not install msys, I wasn't sure if that was necessary. I wish to use NASM for assembly but I need MinGW. Screenie of MinGW folder (after reinstall): http://www.flickr.com/photos/92478572@N03/8404855629/in/photostream

Comment: I can't remember. Does the documentation say "if you only doing compilers", you don't need to install msys? I would start again and install msys too. But I'm really just guessing. I haven't been following MingW so closely after then dropped basic support of a large set of packages, like xmllint, etc. Will try to help if I can. .... I didn't see a message posted to MingwUsers that looked like your issues. ..... The screen shot looks good. How many files in the bin/ dir? Good luck.

Comment: There aren't any folders inside /bin. Just a bunch of applications which close upon opening. I did find NASM shell where I extracted it to and it does open. I don't know any assembly so I can't write a program to test it. However I have tried making an .asm file with copy & pasted code from a tutorial but it doesn't seem to work... will update later. Sorry I didn't get back sooner, had something that needed taking care of.

Comment: I don't think you'll get much use out of trying to run cmds from the windows file-explorer, except for the `bash` (or?) `ksh` cmd. You have to be able to run that before you'll get any practical use from the rest of Mingw (I think!). If you're not familiar with the unix command line, you'll have some experimenting to do. Can't help with the assembler, I have only used the C compliers from Mingw. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I'll look around for how to use NASM though the tutorial I found seems to work.

Answer (score 49):

simply you could run it from the following batch file:

e.g. **C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\msys.bat** (if you installed your mingw in c drive)

for more info. about mysys, check [this](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS)

Comment: Hello @Theodore R. Smith . I created another directory in my `Documents` folder called `C Files`. Whenever I open `msys.bat` and navigate to the directory using `cd /c/Users/Alex/Documents/C Files`, it says `sh: cd: C: No such file or directory`. How can I fix this? I can get to Documents fine, just not the folder I created.

Comment: @RoadRunner, cause you have space in your directory, wrap the whole path within double quotes or rename ur folder and get rid of spaces

Answer (score 9):

Adding the shell link is easy if you have MSYS installed.

- Open your Start menu and right-click on "All Program" and choose either "Open" or "Open All Users" depending on which you want to set the shortcut for.  Open the MinGW folder if it already exists, or create it (or an MSYS folder, as you wish) if it does not.
- Open another Explorer window and navigate to your MSYS folder, in the default installation this is C:\MinGW\msys\1.0
- Right-drag msys.bat from the MSYS explorer window to the start menu explorer window.  Choose "Create shortcut" when prompted as to what you wish to do.  Optionally, you may want to change the shortcut to use one of the MSYS icons from the MSYS folder.
- According to older MSYS documentation, the shortcut should be set to start in the MSYS bin folder, in the default installation this is C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin.  I'm not certain of what happens if you don't do this; the shell opens either way.

Et voilà!  You now have a shell link for MSYS in your Start menu.

If you didn't have the shortcut, the other postinstall bits may not have run either.  The easy way to check this is to look in C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\etc (or the appropriate path for your installation).  If there is an fstab file, then the postinstall bits ran appropriately.  If not, then go to C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\postinstall and run pi.bat.  This will make the mingw folder available from the msys shell.  Things won't work right without doing this.

Update from March 2018: The MSYS postinstall is now a Lua script, and it won't create a shortcut by default.  Best I can tell, you now must do so manually in all cases.

Comment: I did what Craig said. For some reason the install was broken but running the pi.bat resolved the problem for me. I'm trying to build SGMINER.

Answer (score 5):

Look for the postinstall directory, run the batch file pi.bat in there and
answer the file path questions with the correct case sensitivity.
Then gcc is found.

CNTRL-SHIFT click and drag the msys shortcut onto the desktop.

This fixes it.

Pity the installation script is broken...

Answer (score 0):

Go to your windows search and go to Apps and Features and then search for it, you can find the file location and then you can probably see docs and other files :)